# User Defined Table Function with Procedural Logic

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Our company is setting up a new Snowflake instance, and we are attempting to migrate some processing currently being done is MS SQL Server.  I need to migrate a Table-Valued SQL Function into snowflake.  The source function has procedural logic in it, which is not allowed to my knowledge in snowflake UDTFs.  I have been searching for a workaround with no success.

To be as specific as I can, I need a function that will take a string for input, decode that string, and return a table with the keys and their corresponding values.  I cannot condense all of the logic to split the string and decode the keys into one SQL statement, so Snowflake SQL UDTFs will not work.

I looked into whether a UDTF can call a procedure and somehow I could simply return a result, but it does not look like that will work.  Please let me know if there is any way to work around this.

Comment: In order to run JavaScript you need the "snowflake" object giving you the JavaScript API. Right now that's only in stored procedures. For best performance, I wonder if this would be solvable in a multi-step CTE or nested SQL UDF with the resulting "table" being a JSON or array? How large is the resulting table -- I'm wondering if it's small because there's one per row based on the string decode?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Greg.  Is there any advantage to using a UDF over a UDTF?  I originally thought about trying to use nested CTEs etc, but thought there HAD to be a better way.  Apparently not? Its just a bit surprising to me.  The table of results is usually 7-10 rows, so yes, not very large.

I thought one other option would be to pass the string to a stored procedure, then store the result in a temp table and retrieve it after.  However, this would require looping, which unfortunately does not seem to perform well in Snowflake using JS stored procedures.

Comment: It's not so much an advantage as it is the intended use. UDFs return scalar values while UDTFs return tables. I'm not sure if CTEs are the way to go without digging into it, but that's one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think Javascript UDTF is what you're looking for in Snowflake:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-js-table-functions.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mike.  I saw that this is an option, and that you can execute multiple JS statements.  However, can you use JS to run SQL as you can in a procedure in a UDTF??

Comment: Actually, you cannot run SQL from a JavaScript UDTF because it does not have the "snowflake" JavaScript API the way Snowflake stored procedures do. What you will get is the context for every row, so you can get the values coming into each row while executing the JavaScript UDTF. You can persist them across row accesses, but you cannot run a SQL statement from them using the "snowflake" object that's built into stored procedures. If you need to run SQL from JavaScript it needs to be in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

funny I just stumbled onto this as I'm running into the same thing myself. I found there is a [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) function that may be able to accomplish this. As Greg suggested nesting this together in the form of a CTE combined with a JOIN may allow you to accomplish what you need to do.